# Use spring to get rid of main function

Tags: java, spring

Is there anyway I can use spring to get rid of the main function in my java project.

It is going to be a standalone program, and I want spring to get rid of the main function, and take care of entry point by itself.

I understand that main function are a must, but I am talking something on the line of a dynamic web project, wherein I do not define the main classes, but just the services etc.

Comment: Are you deploying to a container?

Comment: No. By container you mean tomcat etc?

Comment: I think you have to build your own app/service container which will be bootstrapping the spring context. This app container must have main function :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You want a standalone application, that is impossible. You should rather load context in Your main method, and just run a specific bean's method (treat main method only as an entry point to Your app).